# run multiple bat-files as admin without entering credentials for every bat-file

Tags: powershell

I have several batch files that I need to run sequentially; every one must be run as admin. This will force me to enter my credentials for every bat-file:

```
start-process C:\test\test.BAT -verb runas
start-process C:\test\test1.BAT -verb runas
start-process C:\test\test2.BAT -verb runas
```

Is there a way to run every bat-file, but to enter my credentials just the very fist time?

Comment: What happens if you place those 3 into one batch file, then run that batch file with admin privileges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nested `Start-Process` *should work*. [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770738/run-multiple-bat-files-as-admin-without-entering-credentials-for-every-bat-file#comment125111633_70770738) suggestion would be the recommended way to go.

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList @'
    Start-Process 'C:\test\test.bat'
    Start-Process 'C:\test1\test.bat'
    Start-Process 'C:\test2\test.bat'
'@ -Wait
```

Or with a loop:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList @'
    'C:\test\test.bat','C:\test1\test.bat','C:\test2\test.bat' |
    ForEach-Object { Start-Process $_ }
'@ -Wait
```